# Andbon controls understanding issue

Tags: dry-box, dry-cabinet

Recently I purchased an Andbon dry cabinet of 155L but it didn't come with a manual. So, I am having problem understanding the controls. I cannot figure out what the no. signifies on the lcd when its is in ideal mode. When I am pressing the temperature button is showing the temperature and it is also showing the relative humidity when pressing the check humidity button.

Comment: have you tried contacting the manufacturer for a manual?  http://andbon.company.weiku.com/product/

Comment: Otherwise, maybe a picture of the controls, as we have NO idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs here. It might fit on a different SE site, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen - I think it is probably on topic since it is about a dry cabinet which is used for storing photography equipment, but it may be to narrow in scope since it is talking about a specific, rare, off-brand model that has no online documentation that I could find.  It is unlikely anyone can answer this question or that it will be useful to anyone else in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be too narrow in scope to be useful.  It appears to be about a poorly documented, rare, off-brand dry cabinet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps!!

I have purchased the 68L which provides a digital read-out of the RH% and Temperature.
There are three control buttons UP DOWN and SET.

When I press the UP button (temp check) it will indicate the temperature in deg C and at the same time switch the LEDs inside the chambers. If I press the UP button again the LEDs switch OFF.

When I press the DOWN button (humidity check) it will indicate the current RH% in the chamber.

When I press the SET button, I can actually set the minimum RH% I need inside the chamber with the UP or DOWN buttons.

I have checked the digital readout and the RH% appears to be accurate but the temperature is not quite accurate.

However, I am **not very happy with this dry cabinet** as it keeps switching ON and OFF very quickly to set the correct RH%.

I also have a WONDERFUL [https://www.google.lk/search?q=wonderful+dry+cabinet+ad-040c&client=firefox-a&hs=DoG&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=etkeUrXvKqOCiQff0ICQDg&ved=0CDgQsAQ&biw=1453&bih=763] dry cabinet which has a fairly accurate RH% reading and I prefer this model as it does not come ON and OFF so regularly. The principal of drying method is better and more economical.

I store camera equipment inside both dry cabinets and I have set the RH to 45%

Comment: What does the display indicate when the dry cabinet is in ideal mode, does it indicate the current humidity?